# how to retrieve child(array) inside another firebase child

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase

I am trying to print `array` from the `firebase`. Actually if we tap a medication in a list(`tableviewcontroller`), it will show its specfic dosages. I got stucked to retrieve the dosages list. Here is my code to get data from firebase. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. My firebase structure looks like this.. [firebase img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlqHq.png)

```
 func loadDataFromFirebase() {


    databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("medication")


    databaseRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in


        for item in snapshot.children{
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("medication").child("options").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
                print(snapshot.value)
            })
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

but if I'm understanding your idea, you probably has a model class for your medications. So, to retrieve your data you should do like this for Swift 3.0:

```
func loadDataFromFirebase() {


databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("medication")


databaseRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    for item in snapshot.children{
    // here you have the objects that contains your medications
    let value = item.value as? NSDictionary

    let name = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
    let dossage = value?["dossage"] as? String ?? ""
    let type = value?["type"] as? String ?? ""
    let options = value?["options"] as? [String] ?? ""

    let medication = Medication(name: name, dossage: dossage, type: type, options: options)
    // now you populate your medications array
    yourArrayOfMedications.append(medication)
    }

  yourTableView.reloadData()
})
}
```

Now that you have your array with all your medications, you just need to populate your tableView with this medications. When someone press an item on table you can just call `prepareForSegue:` and send your `yourArrayOfMedications[indexPath.row].options` to the next view

Comment: i want to print that "options"  in a separate table view ,if we select its medication name. Problem is that in array..so retrieving it as a string shows error...stucked here for long..

Answer (score 0):

- The solution is same as above but with a small change.

  ```
  func loadDataFromFirebase() {
    databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("medication")
    databaseRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    for item in snapshot.children{
    // here you have the objects that contains your medications
    let value = item.value as? NSDictionary

    let name = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
    let dossage = value?["dossage"] as? String ?? ""
    let type = value?["type"] as? String ?? ""
    let options = value?["options"] as? [String : String] ?? [:]

    print(options["first"]) // -> this will print 100 as per your image
    // Similarly you can add do whatever you want with this data

    let medication = Medication(name: name, dossage: dossage, type: type, options: options)
    // now you populate your medications array
    yourArrayOfMedications.append(medication)
  }

  yourTableView.reloadData()
  })
  }
  ```